# If $I$ is ideal of $R$, $N$ is submodule of $M$, then $I\frac MN=\frac{IM+N}N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

$I$ is ideal of ring $R$. $M,N$ are $R$-modules and $N$ is submodule of $M$, how to prove:

$$I\cdot\frac MN=\frac{IM+N}N  \quad? $$

Conclusion:

It's not a "problem" to solve, just a notion. If you meet the same confusion, see answers below :)

Comment: Note that there is no reason why $N$ is contained in $IM$, but it is contained in $IM+N$ is. Much like the isomorphism $M/(M\cap N) = (M+N)/ N$ makes sense because $M\cap N\subseteq N$ and $M+N\supseteq N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pedro Tamaroff's comment inspires my a lot.

$N$ may not be contained in $IM$, but it is contained in $IM+N$.

Eg. $R=\mathbb Z$, $I = p\mathbb Z$, $M = \mathbb Z$, $N = q\mathbb Z$, then $IM = p \mathbb Z$. However $N = q\mathbb Z$ may not contained in $ IM  = p\mathbb Z$.

Notion ${IM}/N$ doesn't make much sence while $(IM+N)/N$ does, so we treat $im+N(i\in I, m\in M)$ as element in $(IM+N)/N$. And it's just a matter of notion. .

Homomorphisms are:

$\phi: I\cdot M/N\to (IM+N)/N,\quad i\cdot(m+N)\mapsto im+N$.

$\psi:(IM+N)/N \to I\cdot M/N,\quad im+N\mapsto i\cdot(m+N)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_1:M\rightarrow M/N$, $I(M/N)$ is the submodule of $M/N$ generated by $p_1(im), i\in I, m\in M$. $IM+N$ is a submodule of $M$ which contains $N$, we can define the quotient $p_2:IM+N\rightarrow (IM+N)/N$.

Consider $i:IM+N\rightarrow M$ the canonical injection and $p_3=p_1\circ i$. $p_3(im+n)=p_1(im+n)=p(im)$. The kernel of $p_3$ contains $N$. This implies that $p_3$ induces a morphism $f: (IM+N)/N\rightarrow I(M/N)$. $f$ is surjective, and $f(p_2(im+n))=0$ is equivalent to $p_1(im)=0$ this is equivalent to saying that $im\in N$ and $im+N\in N$, this  implies that $p_2(im+n))=0$.

Comment: In expression $p_1(im)$, you naturally treat $N$ as submodule of $IM$, this nay not be ture if we take $R = \mathbb Z$, $I = m\mathbb Z$, $M=\mathbb Z$, $N=n\mathbb Z$, then $IM = m\mathbb Z$. However $N=n\mathbb Z$ may not contained in $IM = m\mathbb Z$.

Comment: $p_1(im)\in M/N$ so $N$ is not involved there.

Comment: @TsemoAristide, sorry, I could not understand why $f: (IM+N)/N\rightarrow I(M/N)$ instead of $f: (IM+N)/N\rightarrow M/N$. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Isn't  the equality obvious if you observe that
\begin{alignat}{2}
I\,(M/N)&=\Bigl\{\sum_\text{finite}i_k(m_k+N)\Bigr\}, \quad \rlap{i_k\in I, m_k\in M}\\
&=\Bigl\{\sum_\text{finite}i_km_k+N\Bigr\} &&\text{by definition of the product by $i_k$ in $M/N$ }\\
&=\Bigl\{\Bigl(\sum_\text{finite}i_km_k\Bigr)+N\Bigr\}=(IM+N)/N.
\end{alignat}

Comment: let ring $R = \mathbb Z$, $I = m\mathbb Z$, $M=\mathbb Z$, $N=n\mathbb Z$, then $IM = m\mathbb Z$. However $N=n\mathbb Z$ may not contained in $IM = m\mathbb Z$. So I think there might be some mistake in your proof.

Comment: That's precisely because $N=n\bf Z$ is not contained in $m\bf Z$ that $N$ is added ($m_k+N$ is the congruence class of $m_k$ modulo $N$). All my reasoning and computation is with the congruence classes.

Comment: @Bernard, when you wrote the passage to the second line did you suppose that $IN=N$? Because I could not unsderstand why did you put $=$ instead of $\subset$. Many thanks!

Comment: It just uses the  definition of the scalar multiplication in a quotient. Absolutely similar to multiplication in  $\mathbf Z/ n\mathbf Z$.

Comment: What are $A$ and $M$ in your question? The O.P. has only $M,N$ and a ring $R$.

Comment: @Bernard, sorry, fixed at comment above.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. For instance, $R=\mathbb{Z},M=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},i_k=3, m_k=3,N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. So, $m_k+N$ are the odd numbers and $i_k(m+N)$ are the odd multiples of $3$...? But $i_km_k+N=9+\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and contains, for instance, $11$, that is not a multiple of $3$. Sorry, I am initiant.

Comment: It's often $A$, as  all latin languages.  I think you mean $M=\mathbf Z$, $n=2\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @Bernard, yes, can be. I changed for other $M$, but only detail, can be as you say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99015/discussion-between-bernard-and-naomi).

Answer (score 2):

$I(M/N)= (IM+N)/N$ is just a definition(don’t overthink it!), because every element in $M/N$ is of the form $m+N$ so when you multiply by an $i \in I$ you just get $im + N \in IM+N$

Comment: I did not understand why we get $im+N$. I just understand $im+iN\subset im+N$. Thanks in advance